# Getting a path by traversing backward a linkedlist tree structure

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a tree structure like the following

```
-> grandma
    -> dad
        -> me
        -> sister
            -> niece
        -> brother
    -> uncle
        -> cousin
```

and I have a struct as following

```
struct Node{
Node *parent;
Node *next;
Node *child;
Node *prev;
}
```

If I have **niece** node, I would like to go back until the root, and save that path in a c string, I don't know how to save the traversed path in a string also. If I have **niece**, it should save the path as, **grandma/data/me/sister/niece**

What If I also have **cousin**, and I want to go back to the path, and it should be **grandma/uncle/cousin**, how would I know that uncle is parent is grandma and concatenate it in the full traversed path ?

Comment: How do you get the name of a Node, e.g. a string like `uncle` or `niece`?

Comment: yes I get it as a string, consider I have the string of the node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make this action you can use recursive function that calls itself to find a root and then appends *names* of *nodes* to some buffer.

Example:

```
void buildPath(Node* node, char* buffer)
{
    if (node->parent != NULL)
        buildPath(node->parent, buffer);
    else
        strcpy("", buffer);

    strcat(buffer, node->name);
}
```

Joke iterative example (don't do it!):

```
void buildPath(Node* node, char* buffer)
{
    strcpy("", buffer);

    do {
        strrev(node->name);
        strcat(node->name, buffer);
        strrev(node->name);

        node = node->parent;
    } while (node != NULL);

    strrev(buffer);
}
```

Simple stack iterative example:

```
void buildPath(Node* node, char* buffer)
{
    const size_t MAX_STACK_SIZE = 1024;
    char* stack[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    char** top = stack;

    do {
        *top++ = node->name; // Stack overflow can occurs here!!!
        node = node->parent;
    } while (node != NULL);

    strcpy("", buffer);

    do {
        strcat(buffer, *top--);
    } while (top > stack);
}
```

Comment: can you provide an iterative solution please ? Thanks for your recursive solution

Comment: @AhmedSaleh, As a joke yes, I can. Seriously I can't cause this function should collect nodes of the path in a data structure like a stack.

Comment: Can you write the pseudo code for the iterative function using a stack ? and I will reformat it using my code ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh Sure, I did it in C.

Comment: @what's wrong with the joke iterative method? why it won't work ? or does it have a problem ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh This method would work, but in this case the result is achieved in not very obvious way. The algorithm reverses each name at each iteration and collect them in reversed buffer. Finally, it reverses this buffer to achieve correct path.

Comment: For the recursive version: Since you're concatenating during the "unstacking" phase, while you're at it, you should compute the actual needed buffer length on the "stacking" phase, so you can actually allocate a buffer of the right length and return it.

Comment: For the iterative version, another possibility, given the buffer *and its length* as argument, would be filling the buffer from the end like a stack; and at the end, either returning a pointer to the actual string start within it, or re-aligning the contents with `memmove`. I've used the former for some `itoa`-esque function.

Comment: @Medinoc, thanks for the comment. I don't know what strategy Ahmed uses to manage a memory, so I just shows the method, and show nothing about a strategy. The function can allocate memory, or it can check for an overflow, or it can return a size of required memory — all these strategies are possible.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko what if the buffer is unknown size, If I don't know how large is the path is, what should I do then ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh, You can make two decisions: 1) allocate a memory inside your functions like `buildPath`; 2) delegate memory allocations to a customer of your functions. In first case allocate enough large buffer at function's start and check overflow before each `strcat`. In second case make pair function `calculatePathLength` and call `strlen` instead of `strcat`.

Answer (score 2):

Due to demand from @Ahmed Saleh, I have made a full example for the iterative with buffer and length. It is, however, uncommented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node { struct node *parent; char const * name; };

char* PushString(char* buffer, char* currentPosition, char const *toAdd)
{
    if(buffer == NULL || currentPosition == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(toAdd == NULL)
        return currentPosition;

    {
        size_t freeSpace = currentPosition - buffer;
        size_t length = strlen(toAdd);
        if(length > freeSpace)
            return NULL;
        currentPosition -= length;
        //Note: I'm using a sizeof here, to avoid bad surprises
        //when this code is someday converted to use wchar_t instead of char
        memcpy(currentPosition, toAdd, length * sizeof(*toAdd));
        return currentPosition;
    }
}

char* BuildPath(struct node const* theNode, char *buffer, size_t bufferSize)
{
    char * currentPosition = buffer + bufferSize;
    if(buffer==NULL || bufferSize==0)
        return NULL;

    *(--currentPosition) = '\0';

    while(theNode != NULL)
    {
        currentPosition = PushString(buffer, currentPosition, theNode->name);
        if(currentPosition == NULL)
            return NULL;
        currentPosition = PushString(buffer, currentPosition, "/");
        if(currentPosition == NULL)
            return NULL;
        theNode = theNode->parent;
    }
    return currentPosition;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node node1 = { NULL, "root" };
    struct node node2 = { &node1, "child" };
    struct node node3 = { &node2, "grandchild" };
    char buffer[80];
    char* ret = BuildPath(&node3, buffer, sizeof buffer / sizeof(*buffer));
    if(ret == NULL)
    {
        puts("Failed.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Result: %s\n", ret);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```